# Dynamic mutate case_when according to string matching

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr, tidytable

I have a vector which stores all possible merging combinations for a qualitative variable.
The vector has the following structure  :

```
Config = c("4 With 1 + 6 With 2 + 8 With 3","4 With 1 With 2 + 6 With 8")
```

Which means that the variable with the first value of Config should have 3 modalities : Values 4 With 1 , Values 6 With 2 , Values 8 With 3

I'd like to assign a dynamic value to every element of this merging in a dynamic way, such as :

```
mtcars %>% mutate(Merging=case_when(carb %in% c(4,1)~"Group 1", carb %in% c(6,2)~"Group 2",carb %in% c(8,3) ~"Group 3"))
```

My main difficulty here is that the numbers of groups is not the same for each element of config : For one configuration, it could be 3 groups, for another one 4, etc.

I've already tried to work with string match but this possibility only works for 1 group that contains only the word "With" :

```
mutate(Merging= case_when(
      !!sym(VAR) %in% c(unlist(str_split(Config, " With "))) ~ "Group 1",
      TRUE ~ !!sym(VAR)
    ))
```

Is it a way to do it dynamically for each element of the vector and create the dedicated variable at each iteration ?

Thank you very much

Comment: I get why you may want Config strings, but for the sort of further manipulation you want to do, wouldnt it be easier to maintain presumably the earlier data you had from which the config strings were created ? inevitably solutions people can provide here from your setup will in part involve converting your strings back to numbers, though presumably you already have those numbers, so this would be wasted effort ...  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it ok

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

# Sample data
Config <- c("4 With 1 + 6 With 2 + 8 With 3", "4 With 1 With 2 + 6 With 8")
mtcars <- data.frame(carb = c(4, 1, 2, 6, 8, 3)) # Sample data

# Function to create dynamic conditions
create_conditions <- function(config) {
  pairs <- str_split(config, "\\s*\\+\\s*")[[1]]
  
  conditions <- map2(pairs, 1:length(pairs), function(pair, group_num) {
    values <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(pair, "\\d+")[[1]])
    group_name <- paste("Group", group_num)
    condition <- expr(carb %in% c(!!!values) ~ !!group_name)
    return(condition)
  })
  
  return(conditions)
}

# Create a list of conditions for each element of Config
conditions_list <- map(Config, create_conditions)

# Create a dynamic column using case_when
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(Merging = case_when(!!!set_names(unlist(conditions_list), NULL)))

# View the result
print(mtcars)
```